# Copying Vector Data from one class to another

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ program in which multiple classes are declared I wanted to know how to fetch the content of a vector from one class to another class.

```
void Registration::displayRegisteredCards()
{
    vector<Registration> listReg;
    Registration r1("Niketh", 1234, 10000);
    Registration r2("Parth", 5678, 5000);
    Registration r3("Shilpa", 2468, 15000); 
    Registration r4("Vijay", 1357, 20000); 
    listReg.push_back(r1);
    listReg.push_back(r2);
    listReg.push_back(r3);
    listReg.push_back(r4);
    int size = listReg.size();
}
```

Comment: `MyClass.vector_name = MyOtherClass.vector_name;`? Or `MyClass.GetVector() = MyOtherClass.GetVector();`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful if you added any code you've tried so far. Please look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further tips.

Comment: It helps understand the problem if you post some of your code. Post the two classes and what you've tried to copy the vector from one class to another You copy vectors in exactly the same way as you copy any data (using `=`) so it's not clear what you're getting stuck on. Seeing some code will help.

Comment: void Registration::displayRegisteredCards()
{
        vector<Registration> listReg;
 Registration r1("Niketh", 1234, 10000);
 Registration r2("Parth", 5678, 5000);
 Registration r3("Shilpa", 2468, 15000);
 Registration r4("Vijay", 1357, 20000);
 
 listReg.push_back(r1);
 listReg.push_back(r2);
 listReg.push_back(r3);
 listReg.push_back(r4);

 int size = listReg.size();
}

Comment: @NikethMehta So I've updated the question with your code. Presumably `listReg` is the vector you want to copy to the other class. But it's still not clear what you are stuck on, or what exactly you are trying to do. Please include the other class, and your attempt to copy the vector to that other class. Clearly you are not understanding something, but it is still very hard to know what that is.

Comment: @NikethMehta Another time, please [edit] the question to add any pertinent information. Comments are considered temporary. You can *also* put the information in a comment, but it should be added to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Registration is one class. The other class i have not started with. But don't know how to copy the content of vector to the other class. Is it necessary for the vector to be declared as a data member ?

Comment: @NikethMehta BTW: If you want someone to know that you've made a change or left a comment, you need to `@` ping them with their username in the comment (maximum one user per comment). For example, for me it would be `@Makyen`. If you don't do so, then nobody is notified of any change you make or comment you leave (except in some [specific circumstances (see: "Replying in comments")](/editing-help#comment-formatting)). I'm mentioning this because I don't want you to feel that changes/comments you make are being ignored.This [meta post](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020) has more information.

Comment: @john Registration is one class. The other class i have not started with. But don't know how to copy the content of vector to the other class. Is it necessary for the vector to be declared as a data member ?

Comment: @NikethMehta No it's not necessary but it might be a good idea, without knowing what you are trying to do it's hard to give specific advice. Copying a vector can be as simple as `a = b`, it really doesn't have anything to do with whether `a` and `b` are in classes or not.

Comment: @NikethMehta Forget about the other class for a minute, it's really not important. Get the `Registration` class right first. I'm guessing that class is supposed to represent a list of 'registered cards', is that right? If so then (a) it's very badly named, and (b) `listReg` should be a member of the class.

Answer (score 0):

> how to fetch the content of a vector from one class to another class

You can access a member of a class using the member-of-object operator `.`.

```
struct class_a {
    std::vector member_vector_1;
};


struct class_b {
    std::vector member_vector_2;
};

void foo()
{
    class_a instance_a;
    class_b instance_b;
    instance_b.member_vector_2 = instance_a.member_vector_1;
    //        ^ member-of-object operator  ^
}
```

In this example, the vector member of one class instance was copy-assigned into a vector member of an instance of another class.

Answer (score 0):

In object-oriented languages like C++ are several ways to access member variables of one class from another class. In the following links they are summarized   [How to access variables in different class from other class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507822/how-to-access-variables-in-different-class-from-other-class) , https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14217/when-several-classes-need-to-access-the-same-data-where-should-the-data-be-decl

- passing by reference ( [C++ Sharing variable between objects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457642/c-sharing-variable-between-objects) , [How to access variables in different class from other class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507822/how-to-access-variables-in-different-class-from-other-class) )
- Singleton design pattern ( https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1098119 )
- global variables ( [How to declare a global variable that could be used in the entire program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029272/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-that-could-be-used-in-the-entire-program) )
- dependency injection
- ...